# SQL order by the result of one operation

Tags: mysql, sql, operation

I need to order the result of this query by the result of (LIKES (puntuacion=1) - DISLIKE (puntuacion=0).

This is the old query where I order by the sum of likes (puntuacion=1).

```
"SELECT entradas.* , SUM(puntuacion) AS total_likes
            FROM entradas
            LEFT JOIN valoraciones ON valoraciones.entradas_id = entradas.id
            and valoraciones.puntuacion=1
            WHERE fecha>=:fecha1 AND aceptada=1
            GROUP BY entradas.id
            ORDER BY  `total_likes` DESC
            limit 5";
```

Tried this, but total_likes / total_dislikes are temporal variables and can't operation with them.

```
     SELECT entradas.* , SUM(puntuacion=1) AS total_likes, SUM(puntuacion=0) AS total_dislikes, total_likes-total_dislikes AS TOTAL
            FROM entradas
            LEFT JOIN valoraciones ON valoraciones.entradas_id = entradas.id
            WHERE aceptada=1
            GROUP BY entradas.id
            ORDER BY  `total_likes` DESC
            limit 5
```

Comment: Is this mysql query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT entradas.* , (SUM(v1.puntuacion) - SUM(v0.puntuacion)) AS total_likes
FROM entradas
LEFT JOIN valoraciones v1 ON v1.entradas_id = entradas.id and v1.puntuacion=1
LEFT JOIN valoraciones v0 ON v0.entradas_id = entradas.id and v0.puntuacion=0
WHERE fecha >= :fecha1 AND aceptada=1
GROUP BY entradas.id
ORDER BY  `total_likes` DESC
limit 5
```

[EDIT]

Sorry mate, the query abover is not quite alright. I think the right answer for what you are looking for is this one below:

```
SELECT entradas.* , SUM(IF(v.puntuacion = 1, 1, -1)) AS total_likes
FROM entradas
LEFT JOIN valoraciones v ON v.entradas_id = entradas.id
WHERE fecha >= :fecha1 AND aceptada=1
GROUP BY entradas.id
ORDER BY  `total_likes` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: correct the left join valoraciones must be v0/v1.
but in some cases I get NULL as total_likes :s

Comment: tks  Carles, I've fixed the lefts.. I will check about the negative.

Comment: Well I make it work correct with this:

     SELECT entradas . * , (
SUM( puntuacion =1 ) - SUM( puntuacion =0 )
) AS total_likes
FROM entradas
LEFT JOIN valoraciones ON valoraciones.entradas_id = entradas.id
WHERE aceptada =1
GROUP BY entradas.id
ORDER BY  `total_likes` DESC 
LIMIT 5

Comment: hey Mate, pls check the 2nd query I've written pls. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the first inspired me in other SQL's and the second one is alright!